# Number of Integer Solutions Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An elevator in the Empire State Building starts at the basement with 57 people (not including the elevator operator) and discharges them all by the time it reaches the 86th floor. In how many ways could the operator have perceived the people leaving the elevator if they all looked different to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another result. Start with a small example. You have 2 distinguishable urns (floors) and 3 numbered balls (people).

The possible ways putting the balls into the urns:

$\text{urn 1} \ | \ \text{urn 2}$

$\text{1,2} \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \text{3}$

$\text{1,3} \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \text{2}$

$\text{3,2} \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \text{1}$

$\ \text{1} \ \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \text{2,3}$

$ \ \text{2} \ \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \text{1,3}$

$ \ \text{3} \ \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \text{1,2}$

$ \ \text{-} \ \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \text{1,2,3}$

$\text{1,2,3} \ \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \text{-}$

Thus there are $2^3=8$ ways. In your case the are $86^{57}$ ways.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I ended up getting!

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that people getting off on the $86^\text{th}$ floor is allowed. If not just substitute $85$ instead of $86$ in my answer.

---

Each of the $57$ different people has $86$ choices (first floor, second floor, etc. up to $86$) for which floor they can get off. This gives the number of total possibilities as $$86^{57}$$

This is a [very big number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=86%5E57).

EDIT: I corrected my answer.

Comment: I don't think this is true. This is meant to be in relation to the concept of number of integer solutions. More specifically, I believe that we must use (n + m -1) choose (m-1), but I still am not able to intuitively grasp why. 57^86 doesn't make sense since that is a combination, however people are leaving and are not being replaced. Therefore, it must be a permutation of sorts, not a combination.

Comment: @drshrey You're right. The first person has $86$ choices, and for each of these, the second person has $86$ choices, and so on, for a total of $$86^{57}$$ possibilities.